# DRY way to throw the same TypeError in more than one functions

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I have some functions that each one uses an object as an argument.

All these objects have similar structure, so instead of making the same checks in each function, I've created some check functions:

```
const checkIfOptionsIsObject = options => {
    if (typeof options === 'object') {
        return true;
    } else {
        throw new TypeError('The function argument should be an object.');
    } 
}
```

and

```
const checkOptionsMinMax = options => {
    if (isNaN(options.min) || isNaN(options.max)) {
        throw new TypeError("'min' and 'max' should both be numbers.");
    } else if (options.min > options.max) {
        throw new Error("'min' shouldn't be greater than 'max'");
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is how I am using them:

```
const firstFunction = options => {
    checkIfOptionsIsObject(options);
    checkOptionsMinMax(options);

    // do some stuff
    return result;
}

const secondFunction = options => {
    checkIfOptionsIsObject(options);
    checkOptionsMinMax(options);

    // do some other stuff
    return result;
}

const thirdFunction = options => {
    checkIfOptionsIsObject(options);

    // do some stuff that doesn't use min and max
    return result;
}
```

Is there any problem in this code?

Answer (score 1):

1) note that in your first check  **typeof object === 'object'** if that variable named object is actualy an array it will also give you the type of 'object'. You can see this in your console by entering **typeof [ ] === 'object'** and notice that it'll return true. It's better to use **o !== null && typeof o === 'object' && Array.isArray(o) === false;** for object testing.

```
const checkIfOptionsIsObject = options => {
    if (options !== null && typeof options === 'object' && Array.isArray(options) === false) {
        return true;
    } else {
        throw new TypeError('The function argument should be an object.');
    } 
}
```

Comment: 1) !Array.isArray(1) is also returning true but 1 is not an object...(but you are right about the array) 2) if an error is thrown the execution of the code will stop so I thought that there is no need of checking with 'if'. 3) I don't want to catch the error, I want to throw it to the user of my functions